# Kivy Opencv Android

Tags: android, opencv, kivy

I'm trying to build an example Android app based on Kivy and OpenCv:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import cv2
kivy.require('1.0.6') 


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello!',
                      background_color=(0, 0, 1, 1),  
                      font_size=150)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When running this example on desktop, it works fine, nevertheless when I build the APK with buildozer and try to run it on the phone, the app opens and closes immediately. My buildozer settings are:

```
[app]

title = MyTest

package.name = kivycrash2

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

version = 0.1

requirements =  kivy, numpy, cv2

orientation = landscape
```

If I remove the "import cv2" from the code and also remove the cv2 and numpy requirements from buildozer, the generated apk runs fine on the phone.

Is it possible to make opencv work with Kivy on an Android device?
Does buildozer use the opencv version installed on my system (opencv 3)?

Thank you.

Comment: try `requirements = kivy, numpy, opencv`

Comment: It works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve the immediate crash when running the apk on the phone, the buildozer.spec file must be setup as follows:

```
[app]

title = MyTest

package.name = kivycrash2

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

version = 0.1

requirements =  kivy, numpy, opencv

orientation = landscape
```

as suggested by @Fins

Thank you.

Comment: In python3 I get:

`[ERROR]:   Didn't find any valid dependency graphs.
[ERROR]:   This means that some of your requirements pull in conflicting dependencies.`